# Vertx FileUpload uploads file without extension

Tags: java, file-upload, vert.x

I am using `vertx-web` and trying to upload file. Here is my code:

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setUploadsDirectory("some/path/uploads"));
router.post("/api/upload").handler(routingContext -> {
    for(FileUpload f : routingContext.fileUploads()){
      System.out.println(f.fileName()); // logo.png
    }
    routingContext.response().end()
});
```

Above code, uploads file to the given path, but the uploaded file extension is missing.

File upload name: `logo.png`

File saved name: `45edd7b4-5287-4fba-927e-f256f4b09aea`

I want the uploaded file extension and the content-type to remain as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't configure the `BodyHandler` to do this. The reason why it uses unique identifiers is to avoid name collisions.

You can move the file to another directory with a proper name.