# Vertx FileUpload Unit Test

Tags: file-upload, vert.x

My backend code is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189571/vertx-fileupload-uploads-file-without-extension).

```
Router router  = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setDeleteUploadedFilesOnEnd(true));

router.route("/api/*")
                    .produces(Constants.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE)
                    .failureHandler(rc -> {
                        // handling failure code
                });

router.post("/api/upload").handler(uploadHandler::uploadHandler);
vertx.createHttpServer(httpOptions)
                    .requestHandler(router::accept)                             // The router::accept, method passes all routes defined in Router.
                    .listen(// do things);
class UploadHandler() {
    void uploadHandler(RoutingContext context) {
        uploads.forEach(// do things);
    }
}
```

I have been using *postman* to test the methods. It is working perfectly.

In *postman*, I choose **POST**, **no headers**, **form-data** as body, and choose **files** instead of text to upload files.

I checked in the server that *postman* include the **content-type** automatically.

I am assuming this is a good approach. Please let me know if there's a better approach.

My problem is at unit testing. 
I used the code similar to this. https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/blob/master/src/raw/java/upload/UploadClient.java

There are other snippets which does similar things. But the server keeps saying that no files are attached.

What is the a good way to send a file to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The link in your question points to an old version of Vert.x

With a recent version, you should use the Vert.x Web Client.

```
String filename = "upload.txt";
FileSystem fs = vertx.fileSystem();

WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

fs.props(filename, ares -> {
  FileProps props = ares.result();
  System.out.println("props is " + props);
  long size = props.size();

  HttpRequest<Buffer> req = client.put(8080, "localhost", "/");
  req.putHeader("content-length", "" + size);

  fs.open(filename, new OpenOptions(), ares2 -> {
    req.sendStream(ares2.result(), ar -> {
      if (ar.succeeded()) {
        HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
        System.out.println("Got HTTP response with status " + response.statusCode());
      } else {
        ar.cause().printStackTrace();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

For a full client/server sample, check out the [Vert.x examples repository](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/web-client-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/webclient/send/stream)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried this code. The server is still saying that it receives no file. I m starting to doubt my server code. But Postman was able to send files.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a way to test this?